# PDF drawing objects from view on a page that should be on the next page

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to create a PDF from a View that may be so long it has multiple pages.

This view has subviews of at least 100 height, but can vary.  So i'm checking to see if a view will be split due to a page switch or not, then attempting to adjust its Y value so it is displayed on the next page.   I am using this code to do so

```
currentRowFrame = CGRectMake(currentRowFrame.origin.x,currentRowFrame.origin.y + contentRow.frame.size.height + 5, 728, 100);

if (currentRowFrame.origin.y > 692 && currentRowFrame.origin.y < 792)
{
   int extraSpace = 812 - (int)currentRowFrame.origin.y;
   currentRowFrame = CGRectMake(currentRowFrame.origin.x,currentRowFrame.origin.y + extraSpace, 728, 100);
}
```

A page is of size 792, so I'm checking to see if the origin falls in that space that would overlap, and if so attempting to scroll it down.

The problem I am having is when the PDF gets drawn, it still sees the last (and possibly split) row regardless of how far I try to move it down, and adds it to the first page, then again on the second.

This is my PDF draw code:

```
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
int pageSize = 792;
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view.bounds, nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSInteger currentPage = 1;
BOOL done = NO;

do
{
    //CGRect currentPageRect = CGRectMake(0, (pageSize.height*currentPage), pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -(pageSize * (currentPage - 1)));
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // If we're at the end of the view, exit the loop.
    NSLog(@"%f", view.frame.size.height);
    if ((pageSize * currentPage) > view.frame.size.height)
        done = YES;
    else
        currentPage++;
}
while (!done);

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

return pdfData;
```

my understanding is that this should grab everything from 0 - 796 on the view the first run through, then if there is still space on the view above 796, go again to make another page starting at 796 and going to 1592.

However, it always seems to be grabbing the last row I am trying to move off the first page, back on to the first page, and just increasing the length of the first page (visually) to fit it, while also adding it to the second page where its actually suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

The problem was on the line

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view.bounds, nil);
```

the view.bounds was generating a full page of the entire view, so I made a specific rect of `CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width, 792);` and it worked out just fine.